# How to disable log when start application in desktop from terminal

Tags: command-line, xorg, chromium, gtk, log

I need open new tab in chromium, in other display, from script terminal. When I open, my terminal receive logs from Xorg or GTK (I don't know who print it). I used the command:

```bsh
DISPLAY=:0 chromium-browser &
```

OK! This command open Chromium fine, but my script stay locked because log is sent to my terminal, like below:

```
 --disable-quic --enable-tcp-fast-open --disable-gpu-compositing --ppapi-flash-path=/usr/lib/chromium-browser/libpepflashplayer.so --ppapi-flash-args=enable_stagevideo_auto=0 --ppapi-flash-version=
Fontconfig warning: "/etc/fonts/fonts.conf", line 160: blank doesn't take any effect anymore. please remove it from your fonts.conf
[6423:6423:0426/131721.287597:ERROR:gpu_process_transport_factory.cc(1029)] Lost UI shared context.
[6423:6464:0426/131721.607400:ERROR:data_store_impl.cc(130)] Failed to open Data Reduction Proxy DB: 3
[6423:6529:0426/131721.614429:ERROR:object_proxy.cc(626)] Failed to call method: org.freedesktop.Notifications.GetCapabilities: object_path= /org/freedesktop/Notifications: org.freedesktop.DBus.Error.ServiceUnknown: The name org.freedesktop.Notifications was not provided by any .service files
ATTENTION: default value of option force_s3tc_enable overridden by environment.
[6541:6541:0426/131723.171003:ERROR:sandbox_linux.cc(375)] InitializeSandbox() called with multiple threads in process gpu-process.
[6423:6423:0426/131723.532741:ERROR:CONSOLE(14)] "Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'W' of null", source: https://www.google.com/_/chrome/newtab?ie=UTF-8 (14)
[6423:6477:0426/131723.719742:ERROR:upload_data_presenter.cc(73)] Not implemented reached in virtual void extensions::RawDataPresenter::FeedNext(const net::UploadElementReader &)
[6423:6477:0426/131723.775816:ERROR:upload_data_presenter.cc(73)] Not implemented reached in virtual void extensions::RawDataPresenter::FeedNext(const net::UploadElementReader &)
[6423:6477:0426/131724.152088:ERROR:upload_data_presenter.cc(73)] Not implemented reached in virtual void extensions::RawDataPresenter::FeedNext(const net::UploadElementReader &)
```

This behavior occurs with other application, like `lxpanel`.

Please, how I disable this log or open any application in other display, without log.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Redirect all output like so:  `1>/dev/null 2>&1`, for example:

```
DISPLAY=:0 chromium-browser 1>/dev/null 2>&1 &
```

This redirects standard output to the black hole (`/dev/null`) and redirects error output (`2`) to standard output (`1`) so it also disappears into '/dev/null'.